# POST-method not working in JAX-RS JERSEY

Tags: web-services, rest, glassfish, jax-rs

I have the following method:

```
    package com.restfully.shop.services;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

import com.restfully.shop.domain.*;

@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    private Map<Integer, Customer> customerDB = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Customer>();
    private AtomicInteger idCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response createCustomer(InputStream is) {
        System.out.println("GOT in POST");
        Customer customer = readCustomer(is);   
        customer.setId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
        customerDB.put(customer.getId(), customer);
        System.out.println("Created customer " + customer.getId());
        return Response.created(URI.create("/customers/" + customer.getId())).build();  
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public StreamingOutput getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.setCity("New_york"); cust.setCountry("USA"); cust.setFirstName("Bill");
        cust.setId(0); cust.setLastName("Klinton"); cust.setState("MA"); cust.setStreet("Lane st.");
        cust.setZip("02610");
        customerDB.put(cust.getId(), cust);
        final Customer customer = customerDB.get(id);
        if (customer == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new StreamingOutput() {          
            public void write(OutputStream outputStream)
                                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                outputCustomer(outputStream, customer);
            }
        };          
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id, InputStream is) {
        System.out.println("GOT in PUT");
        Customer update = readCustomer(is);
        Customer current = customerDB.get(id);
        if (current == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        current.setFirstName(update.getFirstName());
        current.setLastName(update.getLastName());
        current.setStreet(update.getStreet());
        current.setState(update.getState());
        current.setZip(update.getZip());
        current.setCountry(update.getCountry());        
    }
    protected void outputCustomer(OutputStream os, Customer cust) throws IOException {
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(os);
        writer.println("<customer id=\"" + cust.getId() + "\">");
        writer.println("<first-name>" + cust.getFirstName() + "</first-name>");
        writer.println("<last-name>" + cust.getLastName() + "</last-name>");
        writer.println("<city>" + cust.getCity() + "</city>");
        writer.println("<state>" + cust.getState() + "</state>");
        writer.println("<zip>" + cust.getZip() + "</zip>");
        writer.println("<country>" + cust.getCountry() + "</country>");
        writer.println("</customer>");
    }

    protected Customer readCustomer(InputStream is) {
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(is);
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            if (root.getAttribute("id") != null 
                    && !root.getAttribute("id").trim().equals("")) {
                cust.setId(Integer.parseInt(root.getAttribute("id")));
            }
            NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                if (element.getTagName().equals("first-name")) {
                    cust.setFirstName(element.getTextContent());
                } else if (element.getTagName().equals("last-name")) {
                    cust.setLastName(element.getTextContent());
                } else if (element.getTagName().equals("street")) {
                    cust.setStreet(element.getTextContent());
                } else if (element.getTagName().equals("city")) {
                    cust.setCity(element.getTextContent());
                } else if (element.getTagName().equals("state")) {
                    cust.setState(element.getTextContent());
                } else if (element.getTagName().equals("zip")) {
                    cust.setZip(element.getTextContent());
                } else if (element.getTagName().equals("country")) {
                    cust.setCountry(element.getTextContent());
                }                           
            }   
            return cust;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }               
    }

}
```

And the following test-client:

```
import java.net.URL;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            String req = "<customer>" + 
                        "<first-name>Bill</first-name>" +
                        "<last-name>Burke</last-name>" +
                        "<street>256 Kilonrinne</street>" + 
                        "<city>Boston</city>" +
                        "<state>MA</state>" +
                        "<zip>02115</zip>" +
                        "<country>USA</country>" +
                    "</customer>";

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/customers");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=utf-8");
            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            os.write(req.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Location:" + con.getHeaderField("Location"));
            con.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When I test the service - the service seems to work for the @GET-part of the class. But it does not work for the @POST-requests given here.
How can I make it work?

Comment: No error. The method just does not start - at least no errors in the server log. The console of the test class writes - 404 - NOT_FOUND, Location - NULL

Comment: Can you post the whole resource class? A little tip: I would use Jersey (or any other) Restful client. Often these client implementations can work on the interface of the service. In your case I would take it, because it minizes the failures one can do. Like missing headers for accept and so on.

Comment: Here is the full version of the singleton

Comment: Just for the sake of finding the failure. try to add a @Path("new") to your method and change the url in your client to "http://localhost:8080/customers/new". Maybe it just the mapping. Are you using a tomcat? an embedded jetty?

Comment: Glassfish v3 with embedded jersey. No, it didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

try putting

```
@POST    
@Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)
@Consumes("application/xml")
```

in front of post function.

Comment: I seems like it cannot find the POST-annotation...But the @GET works quite fine.

Comment: try using - public Response createCustomer(String is)

Comment: also try removing ;charset=utf-8 from your client - con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=utf-8");

Comment: Do you see any error that shows on server console ? Also, what server are you using ? Has any simple POST functionality worked on that server ? Please make sure the server has supported jetty libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I have already found the problem - somehow the client does not work. I used RESTEasy addon for firefox. It works now with this program.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java developer but i think you can use the `@FormParam` to read the POST data. It might help. Just make sure you are using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' mime type.

Reference: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_FormParam

Answer (score 0):

I'd also say try returning a javax.ws.rs.Response including the streamed output:

```
StreamingOutput so = new StreamingOutput() {          
   public void write(OutputStream outputStream)
         throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                outputCustomer(outputStream, customer);
   }

return Response
                .ok(so, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; file_name = " + ltd.getName())
                .header("Content-Length", file_len);
```